# Outputting a List from PDO in Separate File

Tags: php, jquery

I'm learning PHP (and jQuery this week) here for a class, and I'm confused about how to proceed with the format we have been provided. The assignment is a CRUD resume application.

The following code is in a PHP file to add work experience positions by year and description:

```
function loadPos($pdo, $profile_id) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Position WHERE profile_id = :prof ORDER BY rank');
$stmt->execute(array( ':prof' => $profile_id));
$positions = array();
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $positions[] = $row;
}
return $positions;
```

}

What the code above looks to be doing is retrieving the positions added as an array.

The following code is a second PHP file that simply displays the data:

```
<?php

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile where profile_id = :xyz");
        $stmt->execute(array(":xyz" => $_GET['profile_id']));
        if ( $stmt === false ) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Bad value for profile_id';
            header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
            return;
        }

        while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            echo "First Name: ";
            echo(htmlentities($row['first_name']));
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "Last Name: ";
            echo(htmlentities($row['last_name']));
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "Email: ";
            echo(htmlentities($row['email']));
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "Headline: ";
            echo(htmlentities($row['headline']));
            echo "<br /><br />";
            echo "Summary: ";
            echo(htmlentities($row['summary']));
            echo "<br /><br />";

        }

        echo '<p><a href="index.php">Done</a>';
            //return;

    ?>
```

How do I make the connection between the loadPos function and the view page? It's not just a matter of echoing loadPos()?

I need to print this array in a  as well. Do I need to make a second prepare statement in my view page?

This is a piece of the 'add' code for field names:

```
$('#position_fields').append(
            '<div id="position'+countPos+'") \
            <p>Year: <input type="text" name="year'+countPos+'" value="" /> \
            <input type="button" value="-" \
                onclick="$(\'#position'+countPos+'\').remove();return false;"></p> \
            <textarea name="desc'+countPos+'" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>\
            </div>');
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just invoke the function, just supply the connection variable

Comment: I was able to pick up the data, though not via a connection. There is the profile_id that is always missing, and I don't understand how to carry this over if I invoke the function. At this point, I can see data, but the data is appearing in doubles. Each entry echos twice..